# Symfony3: Adding extra security before loading login form

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have been creating web application using symfony 3, and I've been requested to add an extra layer of security. I need to check for a key (or token) before loading the login page.

I've been reading the docs, but majority apply only for the login page. The key (or token) is provided by a custom backgroun app and when the user tries to load the login page, the app passes the key via javascript.

So, I'm looking for a way to first look for the key, compare it to a key stored in my database (may be security.yml).  If the key matches, then load the login page (key is no longer needed after this).

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:**

Optionally, may be is there was a way to grab the key (that is being passed via javascript) and then instead of connecting to the database, compare the key in Twig. So, using Twig to get the key?

Comment: [CRSF Tokens in `Symfony`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf_in_login_form.html)

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about  security layer  like  this , user have hardware tokens  like yubikey.
https://www.yubico.com/start/

then  you install bundle  like  this 
https://github.com/pmdevelopment/yubikey-otp-bundle
and  with that you can create 2FA hardware based security layer (you have  service  for  youbikay auth - you can authenticate  user with this  at any time - depend  on your need .

Comment: That's not what I'm looking form. I want to check for a token (not related to the user) and then check if it is valid or not. If it is valid, show the login form.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your specs, you could:

1. Load the page without the login form
2. Do an AJAX request that sends the token/key to your server
3. If the key is valid return HTML for the login form with a hidden input field that holds the value of the token
4. Validate the token when processing the submitted form

Since 4 is usually done automatically you will have to hook in via a listener, or just submit the login form to a controller and log in the user "manually".

Comment: Correct. I don't really need 4. So, how can I do 3?

Comment: You have 2 separate actions in your controller. The first returns the layout and Javascript that will fetch the form from the seconds action once it reads the key from the page. Then the seconds action returns the HTML for the form if the token is valid.